# How to create a common WPF base window style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any recommended way with WPF to create a common window style to be used across an application? I have several dialogs that appear in my app, and I would like them all to be styled the same (same window border, ok/cancel button position, etc) and simply have different 'content' in each, depending on the situation. So, one dialog might have a list box in it, one might have a textbox, and so on.

I understand how to make base .cs usercontrol files, but I can't for the life of me work out a good way to create a single window which can host different content when launched?

Cheers,
rJ

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do it would be a new custom control, let's call it `DialogShell`:

```cs
namespace Test.Dialogs
{
    public class DialogShell : Window
    {
        static DialogShell()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DialogShell), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DialogShell)));
        }
    }
}
```

This now needs a template which would normally be defined in `Themes/Generic.xaml`, there you can create the default structure and bind the `Content`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Dialogs">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DialogShell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DialogShell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- This ContentPresenter automatically binds to the Content of the Window -->
                        <ContentPresenter />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button Width="100" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" />
                            <Button Width="100" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is just an example, you probably want to hook up those buttons with custom events and properties you need to define in the cs-file.

This shell then can be used like this:

```
<diag:DialogShell x:Class="Test.Dialogs.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:Test.Dialogs"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum" />
    </Grid>
</diag:DialogShell>
```

```cs
namespace Test.Dialogs
{
    public partial class Window1 : DialogShell
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Event wiring example (not sure if this is the "correct" approach though)

```
<Button Name="PART_OKButton" Width="100" Content="OK" IsDefault="True" />
<Button Name="PART_CancelButton" Width="100" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
```

```cs
namespace Test.Dialogs
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_OKButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_CancelButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    public class DialogShell : Window
    {
        //...

        public DialogShell()
        {
            Loaded += (_, __) =>
                {
                    var okButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_OKButton", this);
                    var cancelButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_CancelButton", this);
                    okButton.Click += (s, e) => DialogResult = true;
                    cancelButton.Click += (s, e) => DialogResult = false;
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like it's setting me on the right track. How do I set event handlers to buttons in the DialogShell.XAML ? Since I can't apply an x:class to the ResourceDictionary?

Comment: @RJLohan: You could assign names to the buttons and wire them in the code behind by finding them again in the `Template` (ctor is too early, `Loaded` event works). You probably do not even want to expose the events for those buttons if you only have OK & Cancel as those should just set the `DialogResult` to true or false. (If you do this make those Buttons [template-parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx), so that someone who creates a theme knows how the buttons should be named)

Comment: @RJLohan: Added example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I'm not having much luck yet thuogh - my window based on DialogShell is just appearing as an black window - the generic style doesn't seem to be getting picked up.

Comment: It looks like the problem may be that I can't this line in the XAML; BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}" is showing an error: "Resource '{x:Type System.Windows.Window}' is not found"...

Comment: @RJLohan: Most themes do not define a style for Window, i would recommend you drop the `BasedOn` and use a setter outside of the `Template` to set the `Background` to `White` for example.

Comment: @RJLohan: Actually themes like Aero do seem to define a style for Window, you can use this setter for the Background: `<Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>`

Comment: consider adding an AdornerDecorator to the new ControlTemplate (each normal window has one), otherwise validation overlays and Adorners in general won't show

Answer (score 2):

To add to H.B.'s very helpful post, you may want to connect your event handlers in the loaded event as he's done but instead of using anonymous methods or lambda expressions, consider connecting them to protected virtual methods which can be overridden in the derived class should the functionality need to vary.  In my case, I created a base data entry form which has buttons for saving and cancelling:

```
    public DataEntryBase()
    {
        Loaded += (_, __) =>
        {
            var saveButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_SaveAndCloseButton", this);
            var cancelButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_CancelButton", this);
            saveButton.Click += SaveAndClose_Click;
            cancelButton.Click += Cancel_Click;
        };
    }

    protected virtual void SaveAndClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { DialogResult = true; }

    protected virtual void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }
```

The save functionality is then overridden in each derived class to save the specific entity:

```
    protected override void SaveAndClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Save())
        {
            base.SaveAndClose_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private bool Save()
    {
        Contact item = contactController.SaveAndReturnContact((Contact)DataContext);
        if (item!=null) 
        {
            DataContext = item;
            return true; }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The contact was not saved, something bad happened :(");
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: `Close()` is redundant by the way, setting `DialogResult` closes the window.

Comment: Ya, I found that out sometime later... example modified

Answer (score 0):

You can use define a style in App.Xaml that targets all windows.

This is a sample of how your App.Xaml may look like:

```
<Application x:Class="ES.UX.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="ToolWindow" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then for more advanced scenarios you may need to set the ControlTemplate for your Window.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, the 'style' also includes the layout, and so this approach wouldn't really achieve much, as I would still need to re-template the control to provide content in appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cusotm object , which is derived from Window Class..

http://maffelu.net/wpf-window-inheritance-problems-and-problems/

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Links tend to become stale over time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Xaml Form template and add the template to the VS Installed ItemTemplates directory.

1) create a wpf xaml and xaml.cs file that has all the desired components wanted for a new form added to your application. In my case I wanted the title and toolbar buttons.

2) test the new xaml files through the current system flow.

3) copy xaml / xaml.cs to temp location and rename both the filenames to something you want to be recognized as a good template name.
 a) Change first line within xaml file to -- 
                  Window x:Class="$rootnamespace$.$safeitemname$"

b) Make 3 changes within xaml.cs file to ensure the new name will be copied when using the template -
-- namespace $rootnamespace$                         (//dynamic namespace name)
-- public partial class $safeitemname$               (//dynamic class name)
-- public $safeitemname$()                           (//dynamic constructor name)

4) Now create a vstemplate file: ie.  MyTemplate.vstemplate  with the following content:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>WpfFormTemplate.xaml</DefaultName>
    <Name>WpfFormTemplate</Name>
    <Description>Wpf/Entities form</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>Logo.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>System.Windows.Forms</Assembly>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>Workplace.Data.EntitiesModel</Assembly>
        </Reference>
        <Reference>
            <Assembly>Workplace.Forms.MainFormAssemb</Assembly>
        </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Designer" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.xaml" ReplaceParameters="true">WpfFormTemplate.xaml</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.xaml.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">WpfFormTemplate.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

5)  Once you have all these files, zip the files and place the zip file under the ....\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ItemTemplates\WPF directory.  Now you can go into VS2012 and use the ADD\New feature to see the template, select and rename as in the normal process.  The template can be used in the same way for VS2010 by placing the zip file under the 2010 Templates Wpf directory.

The Logo file should be included in the zip file as well or if you don't have a file then remove that line from the MyTemplate.vstemplate file.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite the same thing as a shared/common base window. This sounds like its just a template to effectively copy-and-paste code into new windows?