# How to design custom styled window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF with mostly Winforms and Webforms experience. I am trying to learn WPF and one thing that I am trying to learn is creating beautiful UI in XAML. I have been trying to replicate the UI of StaffLynx application. The screen shots are present here

http://nextver.com/site/portfolio/stafflynx/

I cannot figure out in WPF, what will be the best way to create the placeholder container for the windows. In the link above you can see all the pages (views) are loaded in a custom shaped window. How can I create a re-usable window like this?

Should I just override the template of some control?
In short I am not sure what is the right way to create a custom shaped window such as the one used by StaffLynx app.

Please advise.

Comment: I think I can design custom window style and hide the buttons to achieve what I want as mentioned here

http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm

Comment: I didn't see any custom shaped windows in those screenshots. You can still see the win7 aero windows at the top with the usual min/max/close buttons....but you are on the right track with editing style templates to customize things to how you want.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of master page where you only have one window and you can change the content?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras Yeah I guess it's something like a Master page.

Comment: @ChrisW. If you look at the images, especially the last one. The content is loaded in a window with Title "NY Accounting". All the views are loaded inside this window with dark grey border and top right corner has a cut. I am talking about this Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ok if you just want one of many examples how to do that sort of thing. Here's a quick example of how to cut a corner like that using [Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), give it a shot. Hope it helps.

```
<Window x:Class="NestedCutCornerWindowCWSO"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NestedCutCornerWindowCWSO" Height="500" Width="800">

    <Grid Height="350" Width="500">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Fill="Navy" 
                   Clip="M0,0 L485,0 500,15 500,100 0,100 z"/>

        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="20" Text="Something" Margin="5"/>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" 
                   Fill="White"
                   Stroke="Navy" StrokeThickness="2"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Some Other Stuff..."/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! That perfectly shows me how to create a similar styled Window. Can you please explain to me how could I create a template with this design and re-use it to load controls?

Comment: I guess the simpler way would be to use this XAML in every page that I build but that kind of violates the DRY principle. If I make change later, I will have to change everywhere so I am thinking there must be a better way.

Comment: There's loads of tutorials you can find with a quick google that will show you how to create a custom window style template for wpf where you'll just create your custom style with the template shown above in it and using `TargetType="{x:Type Window}` to overwrite the default one. You could also make a new control or several other options. Give it a shot on your own first (the tutorials will walk you through it) and come back if you have any troubles and we'll help you out. I try not to mix answers in questions though and prefer folks at least give things a google first to learn instead. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Chris, you did set me up in the correct direction. Just for anyone else who want's to know how to create custom window template, I found this useful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507953/how-to-create-a-common-wpf-base-window-style

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try using a ContentTemplateSelector. Here's a good [example](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/using-contenttemplateselector/)..

Here's a simple example that I made that may fit to your scenario. I have a window that has a border and inside the border is a ContentControl that has a template selector that will allow you to choose which view to display.

Here's the view:

Take a look at the local:MyContentTemplateSelector tag.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="First" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Second" />
      </DataTemplate>
      <local:MyContentTemplateSelector FirstTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" SecondTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}" 
                                       x:Key="mytemplateSelector" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" Grid.Row="0">
      <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mytemplateSelector}" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
    </Border>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
      <Button Command="{Binding SelectFirstViewModel}">Go to First Template</Button>
      <Button Command="{Binding SelectSecondViewModel}">Go to Second Template</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the view model:

```
 public class MainVm : ViewModelBase
  {
    private FirstVm _FirstViewModel;
    public FirstVm FirstViewModel
    {
      get { return _FirstViewModel; }
      set { Set(ref _FirstViewModel, value); }
    }

    private SecondVm _SecondViewModel;
    public SecondVm SecondViewModel
    {
      get { return _SecondViewModel; }
      set { Set(ref _SecondViewModel, value); }
    }


    private ViewModelBase _SelectedViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase SelectedViewModel
    {
      get { return _SelectedViewModel; }
      set { Set(ref _SelectedViewModel, value); }
    }

    public ICommand SelectFirstViewModel
    {
      get
      {
        return new RelayCommand(() => { this.SelectedViewModel = FirstViewModel; });
      }
    }

    public ICommand SelectSecondViewModel
    {
      get
      {
        return new RelayCommand(() => { this.SelectedViewModel = SecondViewModel; });
      }
    }

    public MainVm()
    {
      FirstViewModel = new FirstVm();
      SecondViewModel = new SecondVm();
      SelectedViewModel = this.FirstViewModel;
    }
  }
```

These can be any view model that you have for your pages:

```
public class FirstVm : ViewModelBase
  {

  }

  public class SecondVm : ViewModelBase
  {

  }
```

And here's the template selector. This is the the important part. Whenever you change the content of you ContenControl, in this case the content is bound to the SelectedViewmodel property of the MainVm, the SelectTemplate method in this class will be called. that's where you put the logic on which view or data template display.

```
  public class MyContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
  {
    public DataTemplate FirstTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SecondTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      if (item is FirstVm)
        return FirstTemplate;
      if (item is SecondVm)
        return SecondTemplate;
      return null;
    }
  }
```

It will look like something like these:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, Content Template Selector is a new concept for me. I found it very useful.